# NSLocalizedString for number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I want to translate 1 or one to Chinese or other languages. The number can start from zero to infinity. How shall I translate/show (with NSLocalizedString or other) ?

Comment: Which is it "one" or 1?  If it's the latter, don't you use `NSNumberFormatter`?

Comment: yes. If it is text (One), may I know how to do from zero to infinity? Is it possible?

Comment: That's a very hard problem to solve, I believe, and would be hard for any language.  Even displaying 1234567 as words in english is pretty difficult.  Best stick to numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As trojanfoe suggest you to stick to numbers seems to be a good opinion.

If you want to translate numbers, it can be done as follows :-

```
NSDecimalNumber *yourNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"456"];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *yourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh"];
[formatter setLocale: yourLocale];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber: yourNumber]); // It logs value in chinese
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber: yourNumber]); // It logs value in Current Locale
```